# Create screen if not exist

Tags: linux, bash, process, gnu-screen

How can I create a screen if there is no session with the same name?

Here is a workaround but with a race condition - I'd like without race condition

```sh
$ (screen -S foo -Q select .) || screen -S foo -dm bash -c "while true; do echo AAA; sleep 0.5; done"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where the race condition comes in?

Comment: If the work-around is run twice at exactly the same time, both `(screen -S foo -Q select .)` will fail and two screens will be opened